# "Could not resolve coreclr" path on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: .net, ubuntu, coreclr

**TL;DR**

I'm following the documentation at http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/ for Ubuntu 14.04.

When I run `dotnet run` it outputs `Could not resolve coreclr path` and it immediatly exit with non zero return code, and I can't find in the documentation what I'm supposed to do.

**More details**

- Actually, something unexpected occured before that: even though I added `deb [arch=amd64] http://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet/ trusty main` to my sources, there's not `dotnet` package. However there's a `dotnet-dev` package, so it's this package I actually installed.
- When I run `dotnet new`, `dotnet restore`, or `dotnet compile`, everything seems ok.
- When I run `locate coreclr` I find several files which my match. In particular there's a `/usr/share/dotnet-dev/runtime/coreclr` directory with several `.dll`s and `.so`s in it. There's also a `$HOME/.dnx/packages/runtime.ubuntu.14.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR/1.0.1-rc2-23616/runtimes/ubuntu.14.04-x64/native/libcoreclr.so` file

Comment: For me currently `dnx run` makes sense after installing by [this](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/installing/installing-core-linux.html) guide. But still getting exactly the same error with `dotnet run` or running binary from `./bin/Debug`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dotnet-nightly`. I just tried, it is still working. `dotnet` is not installing and `dotnet-dev` is broken.

Source: http://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Comment: Yeah, I can print the hello world now! Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain this better ? First time linux user, totally lost with these instructions.

Comment: Right now it is easier. Did you try the instructions from: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. Neither `dotnet`, `dotnet-nightly` nor `dotnet-dev` worked out of the box.

But running directly `/usr/share/dotnet/bin/corerun` on the corresponding `dll` worked. It's less convenient than `dotnet run` but does the job.

To simplify my life, I added an alias to my `.bash_rc`:

```
dotnet_run() {
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]
    then
        app=${PWD##*/} 
    else
        app=$1
    fi

    if [ ! -f $app ]
    then
      app=bin/Debug/dnxcore50/$app.dll
    fi

    echo "Running: $app"
    /usr/share/dotnet-dev/bin/corerun $app
}
```

On my computer, `dotnet new`, `dotnet restore`, `dotnet compile`, `dotnet_run` worked as expected. I didn't tried more complicated programs.